# Python - установка программ через код

Tags: python

Интересует такой вопрос: Программа готова к выпуску в общество, но в ней присутствуют разные не стандартные библиотеки к примеру ConfigParser. Как установить данные библиотеки на чужой RPi с помощью кода?

Пользоваться программой, будут не-питон программисты и не умеющие пользоваться консолью. То есть, просто запустил - все установилось - все работает - завершил.

Comment: ConfigParser же стандартная библиотека, не?

Comment: @andreymal это я на примере взял, не обязательно ее

Comment: 1- Поправьте вопрос, чтобы замечание @andreymal учесть.  2- установка программно это плохая идея, если вы не владеете машиной—достаточно предоставить инструкции для поддерживаемых ситуаций. Как инструкция выглядит, зависит от аудитории—это может быть просто: "скопируйте вот этот файлик" (созданный PyInstaller к примеру) или если аудитория Питон-программисты, то " `pip install ссылка-на-wheel`".  Приведите ка можно больше деталей: что за проект (cli?), кто будет пользоваться (Питон-программист/не питон-программист, слово git вероятно знает/не знает), куда ставить. Иначе вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: Упакуйте зависимости внутрь вашей программки, чтобы ничего не надо было ставить (запустил—все работает)

Comment: @jfs а как их упаковать не подскажите?)

Comment: @Insider я упомянул PyInstaller—можно с этого начать. Есть и другие инструменты. Если не получится, задайте более специфичный вопрос: под какую конкретно систему и железку пишите (я не знаю, поддерживает ли PyInstaller и другие похожие инструменты ARM), есть ли у вас C зависимости кроме самого Питона и какие конкретно, можете ли использовать системную версию Питона или свой тащить итд (задача упаковки/установки/развёртывания комбинаторна: чем больше переменных известно, тем лучше).